# How to set react-native keyboard theme to dark

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Trying to set keyboardType on a TextInput with the dark keyboard theme, how do you do this in React Native?

Comment: It is not yet supported but if you need it, it would be fairly straightforward to implement keyboardAppearance.

Answer (score 15):

It is now supported for iOS.[image: keyboardAppearance prop for iOS for TextInput with possible values of default, light, or dark]

As documented here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput

Comment: Does somebody know about the decision for Android?

Answer (score 8):

you can set `keyboardAppearance` in Textinput for change theme `'default', 'light', 'dark'`

```
<TextInput
    keyboardAppearance='dark'
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just change the color in style to black in the textInput style
color:'black'

Comment: this is just change text color in textinput box. for keyboard color change need to set keyboardAppearance in textinput